# How to call function inside procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

how to call a function within the procedure.
I'm looking for a lot on the internet and I have not been able to find it.

My function in package body looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY account_api AS
    PROCEDURE add_new_account
        ( p_acc_id     accounts.acc_id%type
        , p_acc_name   accounts.acc_name%type
         , p_acc_amount accounts.acc_amount%type
         , p_acc_date   accounts.acc_date%type)
      IS
      BEGIN
         INSERT INTO accounts(acc_id, acc_name, acc_amount, acc_date)
        VALUES (p_acc_id, p_acc_name, p_acc_amount, p_acc_date);     
    COMMIT;
     EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
            ROLLBACK;
           RAISE;
   END;
  FUNCTION get_date
      (p_acc_id    accounts.acc_id%type)
   RETURN date IS res1 date;
  BEGIN
      SELECT acc_date INTO res1
      FROM accounts WHERE acc_id = p_acc_id;
      RETURN res1;
  end;
  end account_api;
  /
```

Comment: The procedure is in the same package?

Comment: Yes, in same package, I edited my code.

Comment: You have a function which SELECTs an existing record from `accounts` table. You have a procedure which INSERTs a new record into `accounts` table. . What is the logic to fit the function into the procedure?

Comment: I have procedure for select and delete, I did not publish them

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways how to do it.

1. swap position of methods in package ('sub-function' first then procedure).
2. add the function to a package specification and call it with dot-notation
3. Use forward declaration

I think forward declaration is the best in your case.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/subprograms.htm#i4096

Comment: Thank you for the answer, could you write to me how to call the function. I'll read this

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to call a function in procedure you can call it like average function shown below and store its value in procedure's variable.

```
SELECT AVG(SALARY) INTO V_AVG_SAL FROM EMPLOYEES;
```